# How to remove all the duplicate records except the last occurence in a table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a interim table without any primary key and identity. I need to check one of the columns (branch_ref) value for duplicate entries and should mark the flag as 'D' if the branch_ref is same for more than one record except the last occurrence in the table. How can we do this?

Actual data as stored in table.[image: Actual data as stored in table]

```
select branch_name,branch_reference,address_1,zip_cd,null as flag_val  FROM Branch_Master
```

As per above table, I need all flag to be updated as ‘D’ except for 6th (brach_reference=9910) and 16th record (branch_reference=99100 and zip_cd=612).

When I use row_number function to identify the duplicates order gets changed.

```
SELECT branch_name,branch_reference,address_1,zip_cd,flag_val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY branch_reference ORDER BY branch_reference) RID
          FROM Branch_Master
```

[image: How flag is getting updated]
Am using below query to update flag_val and its updating wrong records.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
        (
          SELECT branch_name,branch_reference,address_1,zip_cd,flag_val,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY branch_reference ORDER BY branch_reference) RID
          FROM Branch_Master
          WHERE flag_val IS NULL
        )
        UPDATE C1 SET flag_val = 'D' 
        FROM CTE C1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT branch_reference, max(RID) MRID FROM CTE GROUP BY branch_reference) C2 
            ON C1.branch_reference=C2.branch_reference and C1.RID=C2.MRID
        WHERE C2.branch_reference IS NULL
```

Comment: You need to give more details and example of the data. For instance, it's not clear if there is another column in the table to help identify the "last occurrence" or what the "flag" column is.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is your friend... You can generate a (partitioned) row number and mark all rows with "D", where this number is bigger than 1.

Comment: @InitK: Have added all the details with snapshot of table & records.

Comment: @Shnugo: You can go thru' my edited question, row_number is not helping here. Also I need to keep last record.

Comment: @RajeshBhat, What do you mean with *the duplicates order gets changed*? A SQL result set hasn't got any implicit order... What is wrong to mark all rows with a `RID<>1` with `D`? This will keep one row for each `branch_reference` without this mark. If you **need other records marked with `1`**, you must change the `ORDER BY`-part of `ROW_NUMBER` to let these rows be sorted first.#

Comment: @Shnugo: I read records from excel and the requirement is to consider latest record as the correct record. Hence would like to mark all the records coming first as 'D' and keeping the last record for processing. I already tried with order by asc and desc both without any luck.

Comment: @RajeshBhat Is there any column to sort after? Couldn't you do this in Excel. Although it might look like a sorted list it is not! There is **absolutely no implicit sort order within a result set!** A simple `SELECT * FROM SomeWhere` can return 100 times the same list, and the next call you get a different order...

Comment: No column to sort. We dump the data from excel to table and then validate and finally process the valid data. So can't be done in excel. Only solution as of now what I got is adding a identity column. But want to check other options, if any, before going for table alter.